# Search form directs to main site from sub-domain

Tags: search, subsites

I have a sub-domain setup with a default main domain (or dual sub-domain if you prefer):  www.example.com  and  m.example.com  (mobile).
I am using Drupal 7.27. I am using Themekey 7.x-3.0 for theme switching which is working, but I'm not sure if that is what's causing the problem.
If I enter a search parameter under a form created on m.example.com, the form submit is redirected to www.example.com to handle the search page, meaning the theme is switched back.
I checked the output, and the form search action = /, and when I use that (as a test) in a link or other reference, it lands on m.example.com as it should.
Does anyone know what might be causing this?, is this default functionality?, and what I could do to prevent it or override it?
I don't have any other redirect modules, or Rules setup that should be redirecting.
Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: are using two settings.php file for drupal ?

Comment: No, themekey is handling all of the switching so I didn't add a separate sites folder for the sub-domain.

Comment: maybe something like base_url needs to be set in the settings.php

Comment: thanks! - that fixed it when I created a sub-domain folder and adjusted settings.php - however it also creates a new problem: under m.example.com it is trying to locate images under a different folder from default/files.

Comment: I just moved the files to a communally accessible area and all is good - thanks a bunch!

Comment: Please add that as an answer which might help other

Comment: will do - once the time limit expires for <10 rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to harshal:

The problem ended up being a lack of a distinct settings.php for the sub-domain.
- I created the folder under sites for the sub-domain
- copied and modified the default settings.php with the correct base_url

This created a new problem whereby the sub-domain was looking for files under the wrong folder (they were under the default folder)
- I adjusted the settings in admin/config/media/file-system for Public to sites/files (universally accessible)
- copied all files over